# Magento 2 PWA store add new sorting in product listing page

Tags: magento2, sorting, pwa

How to add new sorting in product listing page. I have frontend is PWA. So can you explain me how do that.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2.4**

**Sort product custom attribute**

> Create Custom Attribute with the below options values.

[image]

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
input ProductAttributeSortInput {
  sample_attribute: SortEnum @doc(description: "Sort by the Product Custom Attribute.")
}
```

> **Run Magento Commands:**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento in:rein
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

> **For sort product data using custom attribute**

```
{
  products(search: "bag", sort: {sample_attribute: DESC}) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to sort new products.

Comment: can you help me for that?

Comment: You can use product entity_id  like sample_attribute attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain me more. I really not understood.

Comment: can you help me on this point because i have stuck on this point?.

Comment: thanks. Send me message on this skype https://join.skype.com/invite/VhrquOuYhIQr

Comment: send me message on new skype account. this is my new skype account link https://join.skype.com/invite/VhrquOuYhIQr