# Magento2 graphQl special_price filter not working

Tags: magento2

I am trying to retrieve all products holding a special price value.

```
{
  products(filter: {
      
        special_price: { from: "0.00" ,to:"10.00"}
    }, 
    sort: {
        name: ASC
    }) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sale
      special_price
      special_from_date
      special_to_date
      price_range {
        minimum_price {
          regular_price {
            value
            currency
          }
          final_price {
            value
            currency
          }
          discount {
            amount_off
            percent_off
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above is the example query which is trying to run. But it always returns a null result. Does anyone know why it's returning null?

Comment: Please try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353491/82670

Answer (score -1):

First you need to get attribute_id by this query :

SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code='special_price';

Then,

Get special price of products with this query :

SELECT catprod.entity_id,catprod.value,catprod.value_id,catprod.store_id,
catprod.attribute_id,(SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE attribute_id=78 AND entity_id=catprod.entity_id) AS
special_price FROM
catalog_product_entity_decimal AS catprod WHERE attribute_id = 78;

Comment: I need the 'graphQl' not 'SQL'